# I accidentally uninstalled one of my Factory App. What would I do to restore it?

Tags: lenovo

My phone was in my pocket for the whole afternoon until one of my friends borrowed it then gave it back again then asked why did I uninstalled my Camera though I always use it. I tried to open my Camera but it always says "App not installed" I tried to find it in Google play to see if Lenovo Cameras were there but they weren't. I also opened my gallery and the same thing happened, to see... My Phone Camera and Gallery are connected. What should I do? Searched online but nothing really helps...

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your friend is making fun with you. If it's a system app (and there's usually a camera pre-installed that way), it cannot be uninstalled without root access (so you cannot have "accidentally uninstalled" those apps). He most likely disabled camera and gallery.

1. Go to *Settings → Apps*
2. Select the "All" tab (to list pre-installed apps as well)
3. Scroll the list to find your camera app. Check whether it is marked "disabled".

   - if so: tap that entry, hit the "Enable" button, done.
4. Repeat previous step for your gallery app

Answer (score 0):

You can try 3rd party app from store like "Google Camera"..
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera&hl=en

Or if you are ROOTED.. then download  .apk file of the Camera app and paste it into System folder and change its permission to Read Only. Then finally, Reboot.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a factory reset, the stock camera app should return. The reset option is located under *Settings > Backup and reset* menu. You can also try third party camera apps as suggested by itsmeVPawan.

Comment: If the camera app *truly* is stock, then factory resets won't do anything because the app is located in `/system` while factory resets only affect `/data`.

Comment: Exactly that's why a factory-reset *would* solve it, as it resets the package state (see [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/81981/16575)). But thing is, you could also kill a fly using atomics :)